# How can I add a gesture recognizer to a viewModel C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a label like this:

```xml
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="faveLabel" Style="{StaticResource smallIcon}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

and in the C# behind I have:

```cs
faveLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(
            new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {
                    App.phrase.Favorite = !App.phrase.Favorite;
                    faveLabel.TextColor = App.phrase.Favorite == true ? Color.Red : Color.Gray;
                    App.DB.UpdateFavorite(App.phrase.Favorite, App.phrase.PhraseId);
                })
            });
```

As I am binding a ViewModel to this frame then how can I move this into this viewModel code?

```cs
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel()
    {

        var aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            App.DB.IncrementScore(App.cfs, App.phrase, (int)App.aBtn);
            App.correctButtonPressed = (int)App.aBtn;
            ResetTimer2();
        });
```

Note that I would really like to avoid adding the gesture recognizer into the XAML as the XAML is already rather large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to a command in the latest versions of Xamarin.Forms, so you can do something like so:

your viewmodel:

```
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel()
    {

        var aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            App.DB.IncrementScore(App.cfs, App.phrase, (int)App.aBtn);
            App.correctButtonPressed = (int)App.aBtn;
            ResetTimer2();
        });
```

your xaml:

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding aButtonClickedCommand}"/>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

That should bind the command in your viewmodel to your label.

Comment: Thanks, if you have a few moments could you explain a little bit more about the separate class you use.  Are you saying that you don't put tap gestures for example into the view model and if that's the case then how do you bind to them?

Comment: @Alan2 apologies Alan, ignore the behaviour comment (I've removed it now). That applies more to validating entries etc. Think I've been working too hard today haha, heres a link to how behaviours with in Xamarin though, just incase you wanted to see what they do: https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/