# How can I link a button clicked to my View Model?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<Button x:Name="resetButton" Text="Reset All Points to Zero" Command="{Binding ResetButtonClickedCommand}">
</Button>
```

and a view model behind:

```
    private ICommand resetButtonClickedCommand;

    public ICommand ResetButtonClickedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return resetButtonClickedCommand ??
            (resetButtonClickedCommand = new Command(async () => await resetButtonClicked()));
        }
    }

    async Task resetButtonClicked()
    {
        if (App.totalPhrasePoints < 100 || await App.phrasesPage.DisplayAlert(
            "Reset score",
            "You have " + App.totalPhrasePoints.ToString() + " points. Reset to 0 ? ", "Yes", "No"))
            App.DB.ResetPointsForSelectedPhrase(App.cfs);
    }
```

I have done the binding correct as it's the same binding used for many other things in the XAML

However when I click the button nothing happens and my breakpoints in the get and the method are not reached.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a gesture recognizer to a viewModel C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053049/how-can-i-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-viewmodel-c-sharp)

Comment: Why is the return checking for a Null task? It doesn't return anything so it can't be null. Also you wouldn't need to use the command property of the Button, I'm fairly certain you can use the OnClicked property and assign it to your view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure your binding context is set to this page and the view model.

Then, I suggest a diferent approach to your method:

```cs
public YourViewModel()
{
    ...

    ResetButtonClickedCommand = new Command(ExecuteReset);

    ...
}

private async void ExecuteReset()
{
    if (App.totalPhrasePoints < 100 || await App.phrasesPage.DisplayAlert(
        "Reset score",
        "You have " + App.totalPhrasePoints.ToString() + " points. Reset to 0 ? ", "Yes", "No"))
        App.DB.ResetPointsForSelectedPhrase(App.cfs);
}
```